# Non GUI access to Oracle Wallet Manager

Tags: oracle, ssl

I need to import some certificates to an Oracle Wallet, but can't run a GUI on the host system. Is there a CLI alternative?

Comment: Not a perfect answer, but why not run it thru an ssh tnnel via X? If on Windows, XMing makes a very good X Server, and when combined with PuTTY, is very secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [orapki](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asoappf.htm#i637009) utility.

```
orapki wallet create -wallet /private/user/orapki_use/server -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet /private/user/orapki_use/server -trusted_cert -cert /private/user/orapki_use/root/b64certificate.txt
```